# How to update the dom-repeat template to display newly added item in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
   <template id="repeat" is="dom-repeat" items="[[model]]" as="day">
       <component model="[[day]]"></component>
   </template>
```

I am using iron local storage to load data as the [[model]].
When the data is updated using localStorage.setItem(...), how can I have the template to update and display the newly added object?

Right now the new object only displays after a page refresh, because it will reload the local storage.

I tried using `this.$.repeat.render()` as said by another stackoverflow post but that did nothing.

Comment: Try notify, `this.notifyPath('model', model);`

Comment: I get `model is not defined error.`

So I changed it to `this.notifyPath('model', this.model);` then I got this.notifyPath is not a function...

Comment: It simply means you haven't defined an object called `model`. Can you share more code on how you're saving and loading your localstorage?

Comment: Just answered with an example. Let me know if it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pattern I would use would be:

```
<template>

    <iron-localstorage name="my-app-storage" value="{{model}}" on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="initializeDefaultValue"></iron-localstorage>

    <template id="repeat" is="dom-repeat" items="[[model]]" as="day">
        <component model="[[day]]"></component>
    </template>

</template>
```

And then when you want to update localstorage, just update the object [because](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-localstorage):

> iron-localstorage automatically saves the value to localStorage when value is changed. Note that if value is an object auto-save will be triggered only when value is a different instance.

```
this.set('model', model);
```

Comment: It was never broken to begin with, it works in an insolated demo, but there is an issue with the dom-repeat updating in the actual integrated app. So it must be something upstream. Thanks !